# Python Sphinx include directive: ignore the header from included file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I found `.. include::` directive very useful for text reuse: the same parts could be inserted in different documents.

But there is a problem with header levels.

For example, if I have `part.rst` with second level header

`part.rst`

```
Header level 2
----------------

My text to be included
```

and include it in the different documents with various header levels

`doc 1`

```
Header level 1
================

.. include::  part.rst
```

`doc2`

```
Header level 2
----------------

.. include::  part.rst
```

`doc 3`

```
Header level 3
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

.. include::  part.rst
```

It will be always the same level 2. Can't control it.

I've read about [sphinx.ext.ifconfig – Include content based on configuration](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html?highlight=include#module-sphinx.ext.ifconfig), I could wrap the headers with

`part.rst`

```
.. ifconfig:: hide_part_rst_title

    Header level 2
    ----------------

My text to be included
```

But it looks like to create many variables in case of many parts files.

May be is there a more elegant way?

How to include the `.rst` files without original headers? If I crop this I could add a header in each place like this

```
.. doc 1
Header level 1
================

Included text header
---------------
.. include::  part.rst

.. doc 2
Header level 2
----------------

Included text header
======================
.. include::  part.rst

.. doc 3
Header level 3
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Included text header
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.. include::  part.rst
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the [Sphinx documentation Directives page](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html?highlight=include) there are no details for `.. include::` directive, but there is a link to [Including an External Document Fragment](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include).

Found that there are some **options** for `.. include::` directive

> The following options are recognized:
>
> ```
> start-line : integer
> ```
>
> Only the content starting from this line will be
>   included. (As usual in Python, the first line has index 0 and negative
>   values count from the end.)
>
> ```
> end-line : integer
> ```
>
> Only the content up to
>   (but excluding) this line will be included.
>
> ```
> start-after : text to find in the external data file
> ```
>
> Only the content after the first occurrence of the specified text will be included.
>
> ```
> end-before : text to find in the external data file
> ```
>
> Only the content before the first occurrence of
>   the specified text (but after any after text) will be included.
>
> ```
> literal : flag (empty)
> ```
>
> The entire included text is inserted into the
>   document as a single literal block.
>
> ```
> code : formal language (optional)
> ```
>
> The argument and the content of the included file are passed to the
>   code directive (useful for program listings). (New in Docutils 0.9)
>
> ```
> number-lines : [start line number]
> ```
>
> Precede every code line with a line
>   number. The optional argument is the number of the first line (defaut
>   1). Works only with code or literal. (New in Docutils 0.9)
>
> ```
> encoding : name of text encoding
> ```
>
> The text encoding of the external data file.
>   Defaults to the document's input_encoding.
>
> ```
> tab-width : integer
> ```
>
> Number of spaces for hard tab expansion. A negative value prevents expansion
>   of hard tabs. Defaults to the `tab_width` configuration setting.
>
> With `code` or `literal` the common options `:class:` and `:name:` are recognized
>   as well.
>
> Combining `start/end-line` and `start-after/end-before` is possible. The
>   text markers will be searched in the specified lines (further limiting
>   the included content).

but **no examples** how to use this syntax.

Looking at neighbour `raw` directive tried and now it works!

This code includes the `part.rst` from the 5th line (after my heading)

```
.. include::  part.rst
    :start-line: 5
```

or if modify `part.rst` addind a special label

```
Header level 2
----------------
.. include_after_this_label

My text to be included
```

I could use the same label in multiple files to include the file flexible

```
.. include::  part.rst
    :start-after: .. include_after_this_label
```

Comment: I had found the documentation earlier, but didn't figure out how to make use of the arguments. Thanks for the examples, works for me now!

Answer (score 1):

i could do this with myst.

````
```{include} test.md
:start-after: "% start-after"
:end-before: "% end-before"
````

and defined the block i want to extract like this in another file:

```
% start-after

Why accessing to these informations are so hard and you have to blow your mind this much:(

% end-before
```

These two files are on the same directory.
Hope this helps to anyone who needs.