# Include whole text sections from other *.rst - files into this file?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections

I'm using Sphinx and I want to "copy" over a given section from one *.rst file into multiple other ones automatically, so that when I adapt the text section in the first file the changes are automatically reflected in the copied parts of the other files.

*E.g.:*

**base.rst**:

```
This is a section/paragraph I want to see in other *.rst - files.
```

**derivate.rst**:

```
Here is some text. But the following paragraph should be the paragraph from above ^^:

<that paragraph from above>

Here the file continues.
```

How can I do that with Sphinx and reStructuredText?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`include` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include).

```
Here is some text. But the following paragraph should be the paragraph from above ^^:

.. include:: base.rst

Here the file continues.
```

Comment: Thanks but that copies the whole thing.. What if I only need a specific section from base.rst?

Comment: Put that section into its own file, then include it both in base.rst and derivate.rst.

Comment: The `include` directive has several options that can be used to include specific parts of a document. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54518160/407651.

Comment: @mzjn the disadvantage is if you edit the included file, you need to update all the places where it gets included, so I avoid that usage. It's good for `literalinclude` where you can specify a Python object, or where markers are used for start and end. I think one snippet per file is easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn I managed to do it with ..include: <file> and :start-line: 2, :end-line: 4.